# Qt3D Window and two layers, viewports, layerfilters, etc

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyside2, qt3d

I want to code a `Qt3DWindow` where I would have two `QLayer`-s, `QLayerFilter`-s, `QViewport`-s, etc. I need this because I want to render entities in `QViewport` `1` in a usual way and entities in `QViewport` `2` always visible (even when they are actually behind entities `1`).

Here is my code:

```py
class Window(Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root_entity = Qt3DCore.QEntity()
        self.entity_1 = Qt3DCore.QEntity(self.root_entity)
        self.entity_2 = Qt3DCore.QEntity(self.root_entity)
        self.setRootEntity(self.root_entity)

        # some other code

        self.surselector = Qt3DRender.QRenderSurfaceSelector()
        self.surselector.setSurface(self)

        # Viewport 1
        self.viewport_1 = Qt3DRender.QViewport(self.surselector)
        self.layerfilter_1 = Qt3DRender.QLayerFilter(self.viewport_1)
        self.layer_1 = Qt3DRender.QLayer(self.entity_1)
        self.entity_1.addComponent(self.layer_1)
        self.layer_1.setRecursive(True)
        self.layerfilter_1.addLayer(self.layer_1)
        self.cameraSelector_1 = Qt3DRender.QCameraSelector(self.layerfilter_1)
        self.clearBuffers_1 = Qt3DRender.QClearBuffers(self.cameraSelector_1)
        self.cameraSelector_1.setCamera(self.camera())
        self.clearBuffers_1.setBuffers(Qt3DRender.QClearBuffers.AllBuffers)

        # Viewport 2
        self.viewport_2 = Qt3DRender.QViewport(self.surselector)
        self.layerfilter_2 = Qt3DRender.QLayerFilter(self.viewport_2)
        self.layer_2 = Qt3DRender.QLayer(self.entity_2)
        self.entity_2.addComponent(self.layer_2)
        self.layer_2.setRecursive(True)
        self.layerfilter_2.addLayer(self.layer_2)
        self.cameraSelector_2 = Qt3DRender.QCameraSelector(self.layerfilter_2)
        self.clearBuffers_2 = Qt3DRender.QClearBuffers(self.cameraSelector_2)
        self.cameraSelector_2.setCamera(self.camera())

        # The line below causes that no entity appears
        self.clearBuffers_2.setBuffers(Qt3DRender.QClearBuffers.AllBuffers)

        # The code below is what make viewport 2 / layer 2 / layerfilter 2 different from view port 1 / etc.
        self.rendstate_2 = Qt3DRender.QRenderStateSet(self.clearBuffers_2)
        self.rendstate_2.setParent(self.clearBuffers_2)
        depth = Qt3DRender.QDepthTest()
        depth.setDepthFunction(Qt3DRender.QDepthTest.LessOrEqual)
        self.rendstate_2.addRenderState(depth)

        self.setActiveFrameGraph(self.surselector)
```

Comment: Please state your question more clearly above the code so that people can find it easily. Now to your question: are you setting the viewports' rectangles somewhere? I can't see it in the code. The default rect is`(0, 0, 1, 1)`, i.e. the whole screen so I assume, that the second branch erases everything.

Comment: I'd also move the clear buffers up just below the viewport, so that they get cleared even when there is no object to be rendered in the one of the branches (which is likely not the case because you are rendering the same objects twice, but nevertheless).

Comment: No, I am not setting the _viewports_' rectangles because I use default ones - as you mentioned `QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)`. I want that both _viewports_' use the whole screen. But I can see only the second _viewport_ and the second _entity_.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. Do you want them to be overlaid over each other? If you want to have them next to each other (which I assume) then you have to set the rectangles to something like `(0, 0, 0.5, 1)` and `(0.5, 0, 1, 1)`. This way the left viewport covers the left half, the right viewport the right half. Of course you only see the second entity! Because the branch of the second viewport has a clear buffers node and covers the whole screen! I.e. it deletes all contents and then renders itself.

Comment: Yes, I want them to be overlaid over each other. So I want that second entity is drawn over the first one.

Comment: Sorry yeah I understood your question! Try out my answer :) I got confused because you have the two viewports in the graph, as well, but don't need them! You usually only use them, when you want the screen split in half for example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want both viewports be drawn over each other (i.e. not in left and right half), while the first one draws all normal entities and the second one the ones that are always visible.

First of all, I think you don't need the viewports. Qt defaults this to the rectangle `(0, 0, 1, 1)` if none is present, but I'm not sure about this.

The actual issue is this line

```
self.clearBuffers_2.setBuffers(Qt3DRender.QClearBuffers.AllBuffers)
```

because here you delete the color buffer as well, which deletes everything the first viewport rendered. Try setting it to `Qt3DRender.QClearBuffers.DepthBuffer`. This only clears your depth buffer.The entites of the second viewport will be drawn ontop of the rendering of the first viewport.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, Qt defaults _viewport_ to the rectangle `QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)`. It works the same when use the same _viewport_ - the second entity is always visible.

Comment: But now I have another issue: When I translate entities of the second entity, the first entity hides and then shows again (e.g. blinks) from time to time.

Comment: Woops got confused there with your questions for a second, meant to comment this here: I guess you should post a new question regarding this issue, as the original problem has been solved. Unfortunately, I have no idea where this blinking comes from but I experienced it as well in a certain setting.

Comment: At the moment I cannot create a minimum example with this _blinking_ problem. @Florian Blume: In what kind of setting did you experience this issue?